# Syntax for input parameters in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

We recently switched a database from MSSQL to MySQL and the queries that uses parameters does'nt work anymore.

Here's an example of a query in MSSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.ID = :id
```

Normally, the parameter browser would popup and ask me for a value for :id, but in MySQL I get this error :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':id'

I tried using a @ or ? instead of : and it does'nt work.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is this SELECT used in a stored precedure?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

syntax is not the same

```
set @id:=123;
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.ID = @id;
```

[Docs for User defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)