# Syntax for input parameters with ? in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have a kind of same but a but different question as asked [Syntax for input parameters in a MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324560/syntax-for-input-parameters-in-a-mysql-query/27911476?noredirect=1#comment44223346_27911476).

At the above link the query is implemented with `@` Variables. I have implemented a query with `?`. it's not working.. the code is here

```
String queryString = "from OptimumMeasure as model where model.id.goalId= ? " +
    " and model.id.questionId= ? and model.id.attributeId= ?"; 
        Query queryObject = getSession().createQuery(queryString);
        queryObject.setParameter(0, goalId);
        queryObject.setParameter(1, questionId);
        queryObject.setParameter(2, attributeId);
        return queryObject.list()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is it not working?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Actually its running, but its not taking the values of variables..

Comment: Are you using java persistence?  I think you are confusing sql prepared statements syntax with java persistence syntax.  See positional parameters at the bottom here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Yes, I was confused , Thanks. I am using Java persistence. It's not returning the values. It's passing NULL to other method where I am calling it. I don't know why its so.

Comment: I think you are using hibernate right?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Yes, I am using hibernate..

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it seems highly unlikely that you have an "id" attribute that would be anything but an id.

Try using the attribute name of the linked object and then its id:

```
from OptimumMeasure as model
where model.goal.id = ?
and model.quaestion.id = ?
and model.attribute.id= ?
```

Comment: Bohemian .. No no. its not like this. It is ok with the syntax but have some problem with returning the values to other method.