# Access QueryDefs & SQL dialects

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I am running a MySQL DB as backend, MS Access (Office 365) as frontend.

In VBA I am creating a DAO querydef with parameters to insert data into a linked table. This works if I insert line by line. SQL in the querydef looks like this:

PARAMETERS param1 LONG, param2 TEXT; INSERT INTO tbl_target (attr1, attr2) VALUES (param1,param2);

However, I would like to use 2 MySQL features in this SQL string:

1. INSERT IGNORE INTO
2. adding multiple value-groups in one call

SQL String would therefore look like:

PARAMETERS param1 LONG, param2 TEXT**, param3 LONG, param4 TEXT**; INSERT **IGNORE** INTO tbl_target (attr1, attr2) VALUES (param1,param2)**, (param4, param3)**;

I cannot get it to work, as DAO seems to check the SQL string (even though it will be passthrough) and complains as it obviously does not know about these MySQL features.

What can I do to achieve what I want?

Many thanks
krilledrille

**EDIT/ADDTION:**
Code would look like this. I am confused about the PARAMETERS-portion within the SQL string, as this is not MySQL-compatible (to my knowledge):

```
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString)
qdf.Connect = getMyBackendConnectionString()
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
qdf.SQL = theSql
qdf.Parameters("param1") = 12345678
qdf.Parameters("param2") = "this is param2"
qdf.Parameters("param3") = 87654321
qdf.Parameters("param4") = "this is param4"
qdf.Execute dbSQLPassThrough
qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing
```

Comment: Build a stored procedure in MySQL?

Comment: It sounds like you don't write a pass-through query but a normal query. Access cannot and will not check the syntax of a PT query.

Comment: Thanks Gustav for your consideration. I have added the code to achieve it, can you tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error you get? It seems you *are* building a PT query, but `PARAMETERS` isn't MySql lingo. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324560/syntax-for-input-parameters-in-a-mysql-query).

Comment: Thank you, Andre. Upon Gustav's comment I re-did the code to what you see above, 
 and it seems that I indeed have now a passthrough query. Errors changed. After your comment I am now fighting how to correctly build the SQL statement and even more so how I can add the parameters (e.g. "@param1") into the qdf. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: DAO passthrough queries don't support parameters. Connect directly to MySQL using ADO and execute your query using that.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your comments. With your hints I finally got it to work, but as @eric pointed out, I had to do it with ADO. Seems quite a bit slower than DAO, but at least it works now. Many thanks to all!