# Trying to insert data from windows form to database via mysql, error?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I get error at calling `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`.

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'angelina','biology')'' at line 1

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"server=localhost;database=name;uid=root;pwd=xxx;");
    string query = "INSERT INTO table_student (@name, @major) VALUES ('" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "');";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.textBox3.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@major", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.textBox4.Text;
    
    con.Open();
    
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
    con.Close();
    
    if (i > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(i + "Data Saved");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have another look into how SQL Parameters work. You want to use them for the values, not the column names. Then you don't want to concat your SQL.

Comment: ^^ Not to mention you should be using `using` and probably not do Database I/O on the Event Thread. But that's not the problem, here. And also for later: You may want to avoid putting username / password into your code.

Comment: I will look into SQL Parameters more. By concat my sql, you mean I should not use my string query?

Comment: You can use a string query, just do not construct it with "+" (or similar concatenation / format methods like interpolation or string.Format). That is a security issue because it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. Using SQL Parameters was the correct way to go, you are just doing it wrong.

Comment: Never do this: `VALUES ('" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')` i.e., take user input and put it directly into a SQL string. See [explaining xkcd for more](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax for input parameters in a MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324560/syntax-for-input-parameters-in-a-mysql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using parameters incorrectly.  The parameters for a query are the *values* being used in the query, but you're directly concatenating the values (which is a SQL injection vulnerability) and trying to use the parameters as *names* of your columns.

The query should be more like this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO table_student (name, major) VALUES (@name, @major);";
```

The `name` and `major` parts are *column names* and are statically known.  The `@name` and `@major` parts are the *value* placeholders in the query, which are substituted by the query engine internally when the query is executed after you add the values for those parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.textBox3.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@major", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.textBox4.Text;
```

---

**Additionally**, as pointed out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72938415/trying-to-insert-data-from-windows-form-to-database-via-mysql-error#comment128827531_72938542), get rid of this line:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

You're not executing a stored procedure, just a direct query.

Comment: certainly there are duplicates for this?

Comment: @HereticMonkey: For using parameters in general, I'm sure.  But for this specific mistake of swapping the column names and the values?  I haven't found one.  I was on the fence between answering or closing as a generic query parameter duplicate, and went this route.

Comment: It also is not a stored procedure they are using. cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure should be CommandType.Text

Comment: Nice catch, @duerzd696 - that's absolutely another point on the list.

Comment: The OP is not swapping the column names and the values, or at least I see no evidence of that in the question. An equally valid assumption is that they just didn't realize they needed to insert the parameter name into the SQL instead of the value.